# Build dynamic user interfaces with Blazor and XML

Tags: c#, dynamic, devexpress, blazor, single-page-application

I've been researching ways to build a Web Client using C# that is Single Page and is generated from XML files.

Essentially, I want to have a service that generates XML files that describe the UI of e.g. forms (not the problem). Those XML files are sent to the client, which in term reads the XML and dynamically creates the layout with all the controls. I had hoped to accomplish this in Blazor WebAssembly (I have also looked at ASP.NET WebForms, MVC and CORE (using DevExpress), but none of those are actually meant for SPA clients).

By comparison: We have an Android app that basically does this, similar to what is described right here: https://developer.ibm.com/tutorials/x-andddyntut/

But this time I am not developing an Android app in Java, this is supposed to be a WebClient. And as most coders in the company have a VB.NET background, my head of department would like for it to use C#. But I have tried finding ways to do something like this and have met lots of dead ends, as usually Blazor appears to be used with static pages from design time. I haven't managed to get it to run with RenderFragments, for example.

Any pointers with this would be very much appreciated!

Sincerely,

MR

Comment: You and use a dictionary to map the data model type to razor component.

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot follow. I have found ways to add for example a single component, or a list of components of the same kind. But I haven't found a way to add an entire layout including functions.

Comment: As it stands right now, this question is not sufficiently focused.  Can you please show more (code) of what you tried and where you've gotten stuck?

Comment: I don't really have much code to show, as I have essentially only searched for ways (tutorials, documentation, ...) to add components completely dynamically in a layout determined by for example an XML. All I have found though are Render Fragments (as described in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/templated-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0). Those appear to only work with a predetermined list or something similar, not something that works for me, I need to build an entire layout. My question does not really go beyond "is that even possible? How? Alternatives?".

Comment: @M.R. This is a poc i built using json. https://github.com/BrianLParker/ModelToComponent

Comment: @BrianParker Thank you, that is pretty handy! Sadly it also confirms my suspicions that anything one can do with Blazor is using static components, as what you use here is still something that is given at design time.

Answer (score 0):

You can generate the UI dynamycally using [RenderTreeBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.rendering.rendertreebuilder?view=aspnetcore-3.1) but most of its behavior is intended for internal use (take [RenderTreeFrame](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.rendertree.rendertreeframe?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for example) and therefore I don't think it is a good idea.

In short, I don't believe what you want to achieve is possible.

If these XMLs don't change often, I would think to create a transpiler that converts these XMLs to Blazor code and then recompile the app.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to creating Forms dynamically, but a suggested alternative method.

For my application I have a number of services which have different properties but are based on underlying common base class. The services defined in several .NET Standard library for each type. The services are things like VoIP, Broadband, FTTC, Ethernet, Router Orders etc. etc. - not much in common, and very different types of data and behaviours.

The base service class has an abstract method called `GetView` which returns a C# type which is a Razor Component type. Remember in Blazor **all those components are just C# classes**. The type returned is a Razor Component in the same library (so we have UI as well as business and entity logic encapsulation).

The parent site loads a specific type of service, calls `GetView` and binds the service to the resulting Component.

That's pretty complicated to describe but I did a proof-of-concept application for this approach in the early days of Blazor as I realised it was going to be capable of this approach: https://github.com/conficient/BlazorDynamicList

There is also a demo site at https://blazordynamiclist.azurewebsites.net/

I won't explain it all in detail here but it follows a similar approach. There is an abstract base class `ProductBase` that has an abstract method `GetViewComponent`. Each product can return its preferred Razor Component to display itself.

The 'magic' is the [DynamicComponent.cs](https://github.com/conficient/BlazorDynamicList/blob/master/BlazorDynamicList.Client/DynamicComponent.cs) which is a Razor Component with a `BuildRenderTree` method that creates a bound instance of the product's component view.